# IIS hosted service accessing Azure Queue storage

Tags: c#, azure, iis, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

We are currently in this inbetween stage of hosting services on a VM in IIS and migrating some of them to Azure.

I have two services, Service A - which inserts items into an Azure Queue Storage and Service B - which is a Console app which uses the Web Job libraries and consumes messages from the Queue.

As far as I understand the Service B (consumer) must be hosted in Azure and be given access to the Azure Queue, but can Service A (producer) that inserts messages into the Queue be hosted in IIS? Is that possible?

I can currently use the local storage emulator to reproduce this behaviour locally, but it's not really something we can use in production. Ideally I'd like the means to connect to the Queue storage remotely, I'm just not sure if it is possible.

The reason why I want to host the Service A in IIS is that it communicates with other IIS hosted services and uses logging to a file, which Azure doesn't support very well and Azure logging would be very different to how we currently monitor/log events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any app using the Azure Storage SDK can connect to and work with Storage Queues. The app could be hosted anywhere; in Azure App Service, in Azure VM, On-premises VM, in AWS VM, anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> can Service A (producer) that inserts messages into the Queue be hosted in IIS?

Like Chris said, any app on the internet can insert messages into the Queue if it knows the Storage value and key, if you do not want to let app knows the Azure Storage key but also want to insert messages, please consider use [SAS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas/), this is another story. Anyway, please do not worry about this.